# Create a shortcut on home screen to open a PDF file

Tags: android

In my android app, I would like to let the user create a shortcut on the home screen which opens the PDF file located in a specific location. In my research, I found out that we can create shortcuts which open specific activities. But in my case, I need to open a specific PDF file using any installed PDF reader.

I know there's something to do with Intent. Thank you for your help.

**EDIT 1:** Here's the code I tried. It doesn't open the file but opens app instead. Please tell me what's wrong.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/CDLU Mathematics Hub","Time Table For Even Semesters (2017).pdf");
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        shortcutIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "TimeTable");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.drawable.icon));
        addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

Comment: AFAIK, `ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT` is not limited to specific activities. Create an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` pointing to your PDF file, then use that `Intent` with `ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT`.

Comment: Can you please post it as an answer with a sample code so that I can mark it as answer?

Comment: Please check my edit

Comment: Replace `new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);` with `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);` and get rid of the separate `shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare, I figured it out. Here's the code:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Folder Name","File Name.pdf");
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        shortcutIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "TimeTable");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.drawable.
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```